# Sending data from one component to another with BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular

Bonjour,

I am retrieving data from an API and I would like this data retrieved in one component to be sent to another component.
Unfortunately they are components of the same level.

When I make a .log console in the component that receives the data, the data currently arrives in this form :

```
archivedGoodsSold: (2) [{…}, {…}]
archivedLeasedGoods: []
cheaperGoodsRented: (43) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}
```

Here's the code:

The service:

```
  data = [];
  private paramSource = new BehaviorSubject(this.data);
  public sharedData = this.paramSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private apiClient: ApiClientService) {
  }

  getProducts() {
    return this.apiClient.get(this.apiUrl);
  }


  setData(data) {
    this.paramSource.next(data);
  }
```

The component that is to receive the data :

```
  data = [];
  constructor(dataMlsService: DataMlsService) {
    dataMlsService.sharedData.subscribe(data => this.data = data);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chartOptions = {
      chart: {
        type: 'spline'
      },
      title: false,
      xAxis: {

      },
      yAxis: {
        title: false,
      },
      legend: false,
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: this.data,
    };
    console.log(this.data);
  }
```

The component that should send the data :

```
constructor(public dataMlsService: DataMlsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataMlsService.getProducts().subscribe((data) => {
      this.saleRentalInProgress = data['saleRentalInProgress'];
      this.newLeaseCompromises = data['newLeaseCompromises'];
      this.newOffersBookings = data['newOffersBookings'];
      this.newSoldLeased = data['newSoldLeased'];
      this.withdreawnGoods = data['withdreawnGoods'];
      this.cheaperGoodsSoldRented = data['cheaperGoodsSoldRented'];
      this.dataMlsService.setData(data);
    });
  }
```

My problem is that I don't receive the data in the component created for this purpose.

Edit :
When I make a console.log of (data) in the method setData(data) I receive the data. I think my problem is the component that needs to get the data

```
data = [];
  constructor(dataMlsService: DataMlsService) {
    dataMlsService.sharedData.subscribe(data => this.data = data);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.data);
```

edit 2 :

Now the data arrive in the right component but are accessible in the constructor and not in ngOnInit()

```
 constructor(dataMlsService: DataMlsService) {
        dataMlsService.sharedData.subscribe(data => this.data = data);
console.log(this.data); //data received
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chartOptions = {
      chart: {
        type: 'spline'
      },
      title: false,
      xAxis: {

      },
      yAxis: {
        title: false,
      },
      legend: false,
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: this.data,
    };
    console.log(this.data); // no data received 
  }
}
```

Comment: so what's the issue you're facing?

Comment: Ouuups I forgot to specify that my data doesn't arrive in the component that needs to retrieve the data

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-89gfkb) StackBlitz of your code, it seems to be working. The data is logged to the console in your component that should receive the data.

Comment: Thank you very much Viqas for this code. I gave you an answer in "edit 2."

Comment: move your code out of `ngOnInit` and put it in it's own function, then call that function once you have the data in subscribe. Take a look [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ftsnzs).

Comment: Ok i try that. Thanks